# Wallpaperservice example in Android

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

How to use wallpaper service in Android?

Comment: Try this: [Here is the link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html) See if it suits your need:)

Comment: [This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html) will help you; Best tutorial for any topic, Also refer [this](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2010/02/01/live-wallpapers-with-android-sdk-2-1.html) if u like